# An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the UpdateUserPool operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-kms, aws-policies

> An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the UpdateUserPool operation: Caller needs to have kms:CreateGrant permission on provided KMS Key

```
aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id {user_pool_id} --lambda-config "CustomEmailSender={LambdaVersion=V1_0,LambdaArn= lambda-arn },KMSKeyID=key-arn"
```

[docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-email-sender.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is likely one of two issues going on:

1. You have the default KMS Key policy applied to the `key-arn` KMS key, but have not assigned `kms:CreateGrant` permission to an IAM policy applied to the user/principal running that command.
2. You have not applied `kms:CreateGrant` permission for the principal running the command in the KMS key policy for the `key-arn` KMS key.